# Who are Hope's parents?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

Hope Summers is the supposed Mutant Messiah. She has the surname Summers but I can't figure out why. Is she directly related to Scott Summers (Cyclops) or is it due to her tutelage by Scott/Cable (Scott's son) that she has assumed the surname, or been given it?

**Who are her parents, and what relation if any does she have with the Summers?**

Bonus Q: Is she related to Jean Grey at all?

Comment: take note that in alternate universes Cable is raised in Alaska, which is where Louise Spalding also resided. Just something to chew on....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to her [marvel wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hope_Summers_%28Earth-616%29) (check the relative section on the right, there's a show/hide label), her mother is [Louise Spalding](http://marvel.wikia.com/Louise_Spalding_%28Earth-616%29) and her father is unknown:

> She didn't show any desire to "settle down", but she was impregnated by a yet unknown man and carried her infant full term.

She was adopted by [Nathan Summers (Cable)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Nathan_Summers_%28Earth-616%29) and [Hope Summers](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hope_Summers_%28Earth-80521%29). Cable is the son of [Scott Summers (Cyclops)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Scott_Summers_%28Earth-616%29) and [Madelyne Pryor (Red Queen)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Madelyne_Pryor_%28Earth-616%29), (a clone of [Jean Grey-Summers (Phoenix)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Jean_Grey_%28Earth-616%29)). Since Jean Grey is also Cyclops' second wife, she is Hope's "adoptive paternal step-grandmother".

She has no known biological link with Jean Grey.

Answer (score 4):

To date she has no blood relationships with any of the Summers family. She was raised, unnamed, by Cable (Nathan Summers) in a dystopian future.

Cable's time travel device was broken so they could only travel forwards into the future. Cable eventually settled down and married a woman named Hope, acquiring his surname and becoming Hope Summers. Upon the death of Hope Summers the unnamed little girl, being raised by Cable, took on the name of her adopted mother, Hope.

Young Hope then spent the majority of her youth travelling through time with her adopted father Cable until the time that they were able to find a way back to her normal timeline. I believe she was 16 by the time this finally happened. Hope considers Cable as her father and loves him as such.

Answer (score 3):

Hope is raised under the name of her adoptive father/mentor Cable (Nathan Christopher Charles *Summers* ). Her mother is Louise Spalding and her father is unknown (but I believe this is a play on the whole "mutant Messiah" thing, playing on the idea of the immaculate conception of Christ).

Comment: Cable's real/birth name is Nathan Christopher Charles Summers, not Scott Summers.