# Is Hope Summers related to Jean Grey?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-similarity

I'm finally catching up on the whole "Avengers vs. X-Men" arc, and it seems fairly obvious to me that [**Hope Summers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hope_Summers_(comics)) is a clone (or something) of [Jean Grey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey). However, upon reading up on her, it seems that Hope "The Mutant Messiah" Summers was born to non-mutant parents living in a town somewhere in Alaska. She was later adopted by [Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_(comics)), hence the last name "Summers". In my opinion, she seems to be a rather blatant replacement for Jean, but even in-universe the two share too many similarities to NOT be related:

[image]

- Same physical appearance (seriously, she looks IDENTICAL to the teenage Jean. See?)
- Same shy, yet fiery personality
- Both Omega-level mutants (albeit different powers)
- Both have telepathic/telekinetic powers (Hope has a different primary power but still...)
- Both have a connection to the Phoenix Force, which is very rare. In fact, so far the only people who have had a natural connection with the Phoenix has been Jean and her "daughters"

It's also important to note that the Summers family, in particular, have a history rife with clones, duplicates, & alternate timelines.

**Is there any evidence or hints in-universe that Hope is actually a clone/copy/genetic offspring/etc. of Jean Grey? Or has anyone with Marvel commented on the similarities?**

Comment: I cant remember details, but at the time I remember there was a lot speculation that Hope was a reincarnated Jean and/or the phoenix, But then it seemed like the whole idea and storyline got dropped. I don't know if a writer ever came out and directly said it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## At the present time, the similar appearance between Hope Summers and Jean Grey seems to be a coincidence only...but there are some hints by Marvel that might indicate otherwise.

Hope Summers' biological mother, Louise Spalding, was a green-eyed redhead too, described by her own...

> ...*mother as being a **fiery redhead** with a strong will, free spirit, and a good head on her shoulders.*

([Source](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Louise_Spalding_%28Earth-616%29))

While Hope bears a strong resemblance to Jean, Hope (pictured below)

[image]

also bears a natural resemblance to her mother Louise (pictured below)

[image]

Given that Hope's appearance is consistent with her mother's, we can't really draw hard and fast conclusions about her relationship to Jean from *appearance alone* — not without further information to work with.

That being said, the **official Marvel database entry** on Hope has the following comment from *X-Men* and *Cable* writer **Duane Swierczynski:**

> However, although Duane Swierczynski has hinted that these [Jean-esque] powers could be something else entirely, ***he also says that he has a thing for women with red hair and green eyes who can move objects with their mind.*** Hope may also have some link to the Phoenix Force, as evident when the Phoenix Raptor manifested in her eyes, although this has not been explained.

While intentionally vague, the comment does suggest that a link to Jean could emerge, either biologically or through Phoenix.

This is the strongest statement we have available at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

[Who are Hope's parents?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14609/who-are-hopes-parents)

This has already been answered at the link above, there is no known relation. I think it's a red herring (or a red hairing with green eyes).

Comment: If you believe the answer as already been answered elsewhere, flag the question as a dupe.l

Comment: Does that go under moderator intervention category?

Comment: Just click the flag button and it will give you a list of reasons. One of them will be that it's a dupe. Pick or search for your suggestion.

Comment: sorry.. click the CLOSE link.

Comment: Ok, I need 3000 reputation for that. I have 38, so I'm a long way off.

Answer (score 2):

#### The nature of their biological relationship, if one exists at all, is unknown...

The only mention of any sort of biological relationship between the two on the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hope_Summers_(Earth-616)) is:

> Hope has red hair, green eyes and a "close" relationship with the Phoenix. **This has led some fans to assume that she is Jean Grey reincarnated, though this has not been confirmed in the comics**.

You'd have to assume if she was Jean's daughter / niece / granddaughter, any assumptions of her being Jean's clone would have been disproved and would be reflected in the wikia.

Comment: Is that wiki page up to date?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage ...maybe?